# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'u8darts'

Tags: python, linux, time-series, importerror, u8darts

> I am trying to use darts library to forecast price using transformer neural nets. through ubuntu20.4 terminal and python 3.10.

The below is my code, where I just calling and Importing necessary libraries:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename
from os import getcwd
import sys


def fix_pythonpath_if_working_locally():
     """Add the parent path to pythonpath if current working dir is darts/examples"""
     cwd = getcwd()
     if basename(cwd) == 'examples':
        sys.path.insert(0, dirname(cwd))

fix_pythonpath_if_working_locally()

 # Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
 # %load_ext autoreload
 # %autoreload 2
 # %matplotlib inl

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
from datetime import datetime

from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import shutil
import os
import seaborn as sns


import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm


import u8darts
from u8darts import TimeSeries
from u8darts.dataprocessing.transformers import Scaler
from u8darts.models import TransformerModel, ExponentialSmoothing
from u8darts.metrics import mape
from u8darts.utils.statistics import check_seasonality, plot_acf

import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import logging
```

> But I have got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vol/0/home/kherad/reihane/darts.py", line 59, in <module>
   import u8darts
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'u8darts'
```

> How can I fix this error?(I have use `pip install u8darts` in terminal and installed successfully)

Comment: `import darts`, not `import u8darts`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it but I gave the same error. Due to the below link I changed darts to u8darts. [link](https://pypi.org/project/u8darts/)

Comment: see also https://github.com/unit8co/darts/issues/281